# Why is `json.dump()` not ending the line with `\n`?

Tags: python, json

When serializing with Python's `json` module, the `dump` function is not adding a newline character at the end of the line:

```py
import json


data = {'foo': 1}
json.dump(data, open('out.json', 'w'))
```

We can check that using `wc`:

```sh
$ wc -l out.json
0 out.json
```

Why is it doing that? Considering that:

- The serialized JSON is a text file and [text files should end with a newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-text-files-end-with-a-newline)
- The POSIX standard defines a line as "*A sequence of zero or more non-newline characters plus a terminating newline character.*"
- Python's documentation notes that "[*Unlike pickle and marshal, JSON is not a framed protocol, so trying to serialize multiple objects with repeated calls to dump() using the same fp will result in an invalid JSON file*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump).
- Many tools expect that newline (like `wc` shown above).
- Many editors will add it automatically if you edit the JSON file by hand.

Comment: See https://codeyarns.com/2017/02/22/python-json-dump-misses-last-newline/

Comment: On the contra side, it should dump *only* the JSON value and not care about surrounding convention regarding files. What if the file-like object was a socket instead?

Comment: @liamhawkins That seems to be a workaround (which I knew about). I would like to know if there is a reason for that behavior, not how to avoid it.

Comment: "The serialized JSON is a text file and text files should end with a newline".. No, a serialized JSON is just a sequence of text, not a text file. There's no requirement for a sequence of text to end with a newline. That's all.

Comment: There is also no requirement for a text file to end with a newline.

Comment: @blhsing Please, provide an answer instead of a comment to be able to upvote/accept it.

Comment: @Peque Done as requested then. Thanks.

Comment: @kindall In Windows not. But Posix says there is such a requirement.

Comment: @kindall POSIX does [require that](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html). See definitions 3.206 (defining a line) and 3.403 (defining a text file).

Comment: If the OS does not prevent it from happening, then there is no such requirement. Nobody cares whether their text files are POSIX-compliant, and makers of tools need to handle files without a terminating newline. tl;dr "You are technically correct, the best kind of correct."

Comment: @kindall Tools like `wc`, whose behavior is defined for conforming text files but not arbitarary files, care.

Comment: Arguably JSON isn’t a *text file*. Yes, it contains text, but first and foremost it contains machine readable data; which incidentally is also human readable to varying degrees.

Comment: If I, as a user, do not get the answer I expect from a tool like `wc`, then that tool is broken to me. Expecting *users* to need to know about POSIX standards in order to use basic functionality is also broken.

Comment: Also, from the POSIX spec for `wc`, the definition of `-l` is to  "[w]rite to the standard output the number of <newline> characters in each input file."

Comment: @kindall You are free to use ambiguously defined tools if you like. I prefer predictable tools.

Comment: @Peque Note also that `json.dump` does not claim to write a text file; it simply writes a JSON serialization of its first argument to a file-like object.

Comment: @chepner Yeah, now I see it very clear, thanks. ^^

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A serialized JSON is just a sequence of text, not a text file, and there's no requirement for a sequence of text to end with a newline, so the `json.dump` method is right to produce an output without additional white space characters outside the boundary of the JSON object itself. In many cases such as sending the JSON object over a socket (as pointed out by @deceze in the comments), a newline would be entirely unnecessary, so it's up to the caller the decide whether or not a trailing newline is appropriate for the application.

Comment: You could mention, in particular, @deceze's point (a JSON that could be written to a socket instead of a text file in disk).

Comment: Done as requested then. Thanks.

Comment: Except in the jsonl case. In that case every line (including the last) should have a newline. Pandas' `to_json` does not (as of 1.1.0 at least)

Comment: This is also reflected in the fact that `application/json` was chosen as the MIME type, not `text/json`